# GLEnum in Java?

Tags: java, opengl, jna

I'm importing `opengl32.DLL` into Java using JNA and I ran into a problem because of `GLEnum`. Since I don't know the source of OpenGL I don't know what GLEnum is. Is it an enum, int, or what? How do I make up for it in Java?

Comment: I'd very strongly recommend you use a wrapper like LWJGL rather than direct JNA access to OpenGL.

Comment: I don't like using them for a couple of reasons. I wanted everything in one jar, no "add on natives", and a few things such as physics in the jar.

Comment: enums are usually represented by `int`, and you'll need to look at a header or compile some test source to deterimine their values if they're not explicitly defined.  `enum` starts at zero unless otherwise explicitly assigned, and then counts up incrementally for each subsequent unaassigned label.

Comment: @user2306911: "*I don't like using them*" Then you're going to have to *re-implement* it. And that means you need to learn how OpenGL works. If you don't even know what the `GLenum` type is, you don't know enough about OpenGL to be doing this at all.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas I know how to use OpenGL, I'm just implementing it into Java and I don't know what to use as a replacement since I can't read the GLEnum type through the DLL. I actually was looking through it and it was typedef'd as an int, so I can just pass the int value through it of each enum value.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments GLEnum is an int that is normally never used in its "number form" but over constants. For every gl-Function the GLEnum has other meanings.

You can find the numerical values by analyzing the C/C++ or any other native language OpenGL Binding or by reading the OpenGL Spec (I think I saw the hex values in there, too)

Said this, I strongly recommend to use a predefined Java OpenGL binding instead. There is no win by avoiding 3th party jars in the build path. Thats the way java works.